# Why PMC values are so large when instrumenting in Xcode counters

Tags: macos, profiling, instruments, performancecounter

I am new to Xcode Instruments, but not to computer architecture. I am instrumenting to see how many clock cycles the processor took to launch an application in MacOS. As an example, I used MacOS Calendar app and ran it for around a second of wall clock time. The number of cycles on my KabyLake machine using a 2.3 GHz Quadcore I5 is being reported as 4.1 * 10^21.

The above number doesn't make sense. I cannot have that many cycles on a processor running at Ghz frequency. What am I missing? How do I find the number of ticks that were used by my calendar thread?

[image: Here is the snapshot of Instruments]